# How to edit citation style based on custom bst file using natbib? (Bibtex)

Tags: citing, natbib

here I use a custom bst file and my output of `\citep[434]{needham}` is

> (Needham, 1997, 434)

And I want it to be

> (Needham, 1997:434)

Notice that there's no space after colon. How to accomplish this by editing my custom bst file or maybe using `\setcitestyle` to redefine the citation style using colon without space between year and page?

I tried to put `\setcitestyle{notesep={:},round,aysep={, },citesep={; }}` after backmatter and `\bibliography{mycustombststyle}`  but didn't work

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The formatting of the page number/postnote in citations is not controlled by the `.bst` file. If and how it can be controlled will depend on the citation/bibliography packages you load and how you use them in your document. With standard `natbib` I would have `\setcitestyle` to work in principle, but it is very possible that there is some code in your document that stops it from doing what you want. I'm afraid we will only be able to help you if you can share a short, but compilable example document with us that shows how `\setcitestyle` does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe you could tell me how to put `\setcitestyle` correctly? Perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: By the way I put `\setcitestyle` on backmatter inside the begin document and after `bibliography{mycustombststyle}`

Comment: You should probably put it into the preamble, but I'm afraid that is all I can say at the moment.

Comment: @moewe Oh yes!. That's working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> I tried to put `\setcitestyle{notesep={:},round,aysep={, },citesep={; }}` after `\backmatter` ... but [it] didn't work.

`\setcitestyle` is a prime example of a command that belongs in the preamble -- or, at the very latest, *before* the first instance of a `\cite`-like directive in the main body of the document. Why? Unlike `\bibliographystyle` -- which gets written to the aux file, serves to inform what BibTeX is supposed to do, and hence can occur pretty much anywhere before `\end{document}` -- `\setcitestyle` affects the way how LaTeX (*not* BibTeX) goes about its job of creating citation call-outs.

In short, place the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{round, aysep={, }, notesep={:}, citesep={; }}
```

in the preamble, ideally immediately after loading the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: Thanks for the information Mico

Comment: Thanks for the information Mico